# Can I create a bunch of reactive input-output pairs from a list in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny, is it possible to create several reactive input-output pairs from a vector/list of strings using a functional?

i.e something like

```
id_list <- c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3")

server <- function(input, output) {

lapply(id_list, function(x) quote(output$as.character(x) <- renderText({ input$x })))

}
```

The result would in effect be

```
output$ID_1 <- renderText({ input$ID_1 })
output$ID_2 <- renderText({ input$ID_2 })
output$ID_2 <- renderText({ input$ID_2 })
```

etc. for all items in the list, with each working in a reactive manner in the server function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
server <- function(input, output) {
 
  for(id in id_list){
    local({
      localId <- id
      output[[localId]] <- renderText({
        input[[localId]]
      })
    })
  } 

}
```

Comment: So it can't be done inside a functional like lapply?

Comment: @eartoolbox You can try `lapply(id_list, function(id){output[[id]] <- renderText({input[[id]]})})`.